# How to differentiate Capacitance (Italized C) and Coloumbs (regular C) on paper

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance, notation

I am doing a question on capacitance and coulombs. I got the answer correct, but I was wondering how a physicist, when doing the calculation on paper, would differentiate a *C* and C?

Comment: Capacitance is measured in *Farads*, with an "F".

Comment: When the equation is in terms of symbols, $C$ probably indicates some capacitance. When you are using the equation to calculate something by substituting numerical values for all the symbols, then C is probably the unit (Coulomb) for the value of some symbol that represented a charge. This does not tend to create confusion unless you substitute values for some symbols and not others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will omit the fact that capacitance is measured in Farads, as I see a more general use to the question. For the sake of this answer I will answer as if we are symbolically manipulating capacitance and use the variable $C$.

---

I usually don't have this issue with capacitance, but when I want to make explicit that I'm using a capital letter that is non italicized what I'll do is put a line under it. For instance I would write $C$ for capacitance and $\underline{C}$ for coulombs.

Like I said this is probably overkill for capacitance and coulombs, but **I think it's useful in a broader context**.

**Downfalls**: If you're writing fast it can get kind of messy if your capital letter appears in the numerator like $\frac{\underline{C}}{C}$ and wind up looking awkward, so I only do this if I know it's not going to be an issue.

**2$^{nd}$ solution**:If it is unavoidable and the algebra will get nasty I will write my capital letters as "double struck". So for instance $\mathbb{C}$ would be Coulombs in this case, and I just close my eyes and hope that I don't need to mention the complex numbers.

Comment: Or just C for coulombs, C1, C2, ... for different capacitances.

Comment: That's fair, but I was trying to give an answer that was more general and so may be useful ini a broader context